# Opencv and Image Processing: Extracting contour of the body frame

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour, motion-detection, threshold

I am a beginner in image processing and just started fiddling with OpenCV for a project. I have a video signal of pedestrian walking.I am running the pedestrain.cpp program whic does th bckgound subtrction uing HOG and want to do something like the image attached [image].I have done the following after the peson is detected

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);    
    if (!cap.isOpened())
        return -1;

    Mat img;
    HOGDescriptor hog;
    hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());
    if((WriteFP=fopen("output.txt", "w")) == NULL) ErrorExit(ER_WRITE_OPEN);


    namedWindow("video capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Motion", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);


    while (true)
    {
        cap >> img;
        if (!img.data)
            continue;

        vector<Rect> found, found_filtered;
        hog.detectMultiScale(img, found, 0, Size(8,8), Size(32,32), 1.05, 2);

        size_t i, j;
        for (i=0; i<found.size(); i++)
        {
            Rect r = found[i];
            for (j=0; j<found.size(); j++)
                if (j!=i && (r & found[j])==r)
                    break;
            if (j==found.size())
                found_filtered.push_back(r);
        }
        for (i=0; i<found_filtered.size(); i++)
        {
        Rect r = found_filtered[i];
            r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);
        r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.8);
        r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.06);
        r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.9);
        rectangle(img, r.tl(), r.br(), cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 2);
        }
        imshow("video capture", img);
        IplImage *mat_img;

        mat_img=cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)img);
        cvThreshold(img,img, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    cvDilate(img, img, 0,1);
    cvErode(img, img, 0, 0);
    cvFindContours(img, storage_contours, &contours, sizeof(CvContour),
    CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0, 0));
}
```

But,I am unable to get te output frames like the one in thepicture.Can somebody tell me what needs to  be done. Thank you

Comment: do not mix a HoG ( Histogramm of Gradient ) Person detektor with an Background Modelling / Background Substraction technique. From a Person detektor you get a bounding box, from a Background Modelling method you get a shilouette of the foreground objects.

Comment: Thank you.I tried with background subtraction but could not get the silhouette like the one in the picture.Could you kindly post the code or perhaps a link whereby I can get the silhouette.

Comment: Could you explain, what your input data is or what your exact question is? Do you have RGB video of a pedestrian and want a Foreground/Shilouhette mask as you have show on top? Or did you search for a method that extract the shilouhette and your input video is a foreground mask as you had shown ton top.

Comment: I have an RGB video of pedestrian and want a silhouette mask as shown in the figure.

Comment: If you could post your results and a sample of the input image, perhaps we could help you be paramerize your method. I have very good expirences with the "Splitting Gaussians in Mixture Models" method by Ruben Heras Evangelio

Answer (score 0):

At the [Change Detection Benchmark](http://www.changedetection.net/) you will find an overview of state-of-the-art Background modelling methods and implementations.

OpenCV provides the [BackgroundSubtractorMOG](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=background#BackgroundSubtractorMOG2%20%3a%20public%20BackgroundSubtractor) class for background modelling and foreground substraction.

Most of the methods train a pixelwise statistic of the the color of the background and decide if a pixel is foreground or background if the pixel color do not belong to the background statistics. Consequently these methods need a set of trainingsamples (images) to learn the background. You should also mention that similar colors of background and foreground objects could leed to holes in the foreground mask, since the algorithm is only able to devide between these two classes by means of color.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I still do not understand how to mention the threshold.I just implemented the peopledetect.cpp program avaialble in OpenCV resources.The program draws boundary boxes around the humans detected.I believe there are a set of fixed parameters for the size of the bounding box.So,I was wondering if the background subtraction technique mentioned by you and how to go about it.Actually,I hardly have any knowledge about image processing and I just dived into  it for a small project requirement.